# PHP: pdo_oci driver does not work under apache, but does work from console

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle-call-interface

I'm having a very puzzling situation with PHP PDO and Oracle. I'm
running on Centos 7.  My script, under Apache gets the error
"ERROR:could not find driver", however the script runs fine from the command line.

From the command line when I run a test script to list the drivers:

foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver)
        echo $driver, '
', "\n";

it returns:

> mysql
>  oci
>  pgsql
>  sqlite

but when run under apache, oci is missing:

> mysql
>  pgsql
>  sqlite

To add to this mystery, running phpinfo() shows in the section
"Additional .ini files parsed" an entry for /etc/php.d/pdo_oci.ini (for both console and apache).

Any ideas as to why the oci driver is not showing up when the script
is run under apache?

Comment: Can you compare the output of `php -m` under the CLI and the [`get_loaded_extensions()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) in apache?

Comment: Hi apokryfos.  It shows the same situation.  php -m shows "PDO_OCI", but there is no corresponding module for get_loaded_extensions() under apache.  It's a pretty long list to post. Was there anything specific you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" this problem by punting on getting it to work using the Oracle installation configuration.  I installed Instant Client and that got PHP to recognize the oci module both in command line and under apache (building pdo_oci with ./configure --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr,11.2)

There were further issues with unrecognized TNS_ADMIN values.  I worked around that by using the alternative PDO DSN spec for Oracle connections:

> oci:dbname=//HOST[:PORT]/SERVICE_NAME

Thanks to anyone kind enough to have spent time on this.  This experience, like many Oracle-related ones, reminds me why I use Postgres.